# js is not working in head tag ( cake php )

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I am new to cake php.  if i am including js in head tag in default.ctp like this

```
    //including js 
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.jcarousel.pack');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.4.1.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-func');
```

it is not working. Even i can see the whole code from above files via view page source (browser option). But working for alerts.

if i m putting all the code from each js file directly in script  tags . Then it is working fine without any problem.

somebody help me about it.

Comment: I would think you need to include jquery before jcarousel

Comment: are you using the folder webroot/js?

Comment: yes all js  files are in webroot/js folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1672632/rob-schmuecker its working now ...

Answer (score 0):

```
//including js 
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.4.1.min');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.jcarousel.pack');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-func');
```